# Proof of $+0 = -0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do you prove  $+ 0 = - 0$  ?

I have no clue where to start from. (I am a 11th Grader). Can it be done only using concepts I have learned till now or will I need some more concepts?

Comment: I think what you want to prove is that the additive inverse of $0$, denoted by $-0$, equals $0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if I denote $+0$ by $0$, which is correct. (I assume)

Comment: I'm jealous that you got to learn these axioms in high school. Didn't see these until I was well into college.

Comment: @Clarinetist Where did OP say he learned any axioms?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Why else would the OP be asking such a question? Furthermore, given the answer by Noble Mushtak below and OP's comment, it's pretty clear that the OP learned the field axioms.

Comment: I don't know what a field axiom is. But I still can understand NobleMushtak's answer

Comment: @SS_C4 [List of Field Axioms](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~rcp/FieldAxioms.pdf).

Comment: I learned the zero property of addition ($0+a=a$) in Grade 3 and I think the cancellation property of addition ($a+(-a)=0$) is taught with negative numbers which is introduced in Grade 5. (I skipped Grade 4-6 math, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @SS_C4 Try [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html).

Comment: Ok, yeah. I've learnt them, but not under the name of Field Axioms

Comment: @SS_C4 Any set satisfying the field axioms is called a field. The set of reals and the set of rationals are both fields, but the set of integers is not since it doesn't have multiplicative inverses.

Comment: @SS_C4 The set $\{0,1\}$ is not a field, since the sum $1+1$ is not in this set. _However_, we can make it a field! Define a new operation $\widetilde+$ by the equations $0\ \widetilde+\ 0=0$, $0\ \widetilde+\ 1=1$, $1\ \widetilde+\ 0=1$, and $1\ \widetilde+\ 1=0$. Now, the set $\{0,1\}$ is a field where the summation operation is $\widetilde+$ and the multiplication operation is $\times$. (Check the axioms, it works.)

Comment: Question araises what $-0$ exactly _is_. Releated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808347/is-x-x-true-for-x-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the definition of $0$, $0$ is the additive identity of $\Bbb{R}$, meaning for all $a \in \Bbb{R}$: $$0+a=a$$

Also, from the definition of negative numbers, for all $b \in \Bbb{R}$:
$$b+(-b)=0$$

Thus, if we let $b=0$ in the second equation, we get:
$$0+(-0)=0$$

Also, if we let $a=-0$ in the first equation, we get:
$$0+(-0)=-0$$

Thus, by the Transitive Property of Equality with the last two equations, $-0=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my post when I went to edit it, but I've undeleted it now, so it's back.

Comment: It is not "well-known" in the sense that it is some sort of result. It is an axiom.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I've edited my post to clarify that these properties come from the definition of a field and aren't just theorems.

Answer (score 11):

$0$ is the unique(!) number with the property $$\tag1x+0=x$$ for all $x$.
For any $y$, $-y$ is the unique(!) number with the property $$\tag2y+(-y)=0.$$

From $(1)$ with $x=0$, we get the following:
$$0+0=0$$

Also, from $(2)$ with $y=0$, we get the following:
$$0+(-0)=0$$

Thus, by the Transitive Property of Equality, we can set the left side of both of the previous equations equal to each other:
$$0+0=0+(-0)$$

Hence, by the Subtractive Property of Equality, we subtract $0$ from both sides of this equation to see that $-0=0$.

(NOTE: The $+$ in $+0$ being redundant and/or misleading)

Comment: Can I say $-0$ is also a number with the property $x + (-0) = x$

Comment: @SS_C4 You'd have to prove that before you can use that.

Comment: @SS_C4 How do you prove that without proving $-0=0$ first?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the reverse? I should not be able to prove $0 = -0$ without proving that first?

Comment: @SS_C4 I clearly proved $0=-0$ without using that property.

Comment: No, I meant by using @Hagen's method.
Because it seems cyclic to me.

Comment: What @Hagen did is that he found $0+0=0$ using $(1)$ and $0+(-0)=0$ from $(2)$. He then used the Transitive Property of Equality to show that $0+0=0+(-0)$ and subtracted both sides of the equation by $0$ using the Subtractive Property of Equality to show $0=-0$.

Comment: Pardon me, but too many $0$'s over the past few hours has me confused.

Comment: @SS_C4 I edited the answer above to clarify it.