# Is $|x| = -x$ true for $x = 0$?

Tags: number-theory, definition

What are the solutions for this equation?

$|x| = -x$

It is clear for me that all negative numbers will fulfill this (my brother doesn't believe me, but that doesn't matter). But I'm having a discussion with my mum about whether $x=0$ fulfils it. My mum says something like "There isn't a $-0$ so this doesn't work!". I don't believe this.

Is the equation true for $x=0$? Why or why not? What is this $-0$ thing?

Comment: I can only say that you have serious troubles in your family!

Comment: @guestDiego no, just a nice discussion ;-)

Comment: The additive inverse (ie. "negative") of a number $a$ is the unique number $-a$ such that $(a) + (-a) = 0$. If $a=0$, what is $-a$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 a=0 and a+(-a)=0 => -a=0 ?

Comment: Sure: $|0| = 0 = -0$.

Comment: By definition $-0$ is the unique number that satisfies the equation $0+(-0)=0$. Also it is obvious that $0+0=0$. Then the uniqueness tells us that $-0=0$.

Comment: @drhab: I hadn't seen your comment before I started writing my answer. But I think this is the right way to think about it.

Comment: @drhab: Does $-0$ even make sense in view of [Peano Axioms](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNs_WniIfNAhXDipQKHWtXAXAQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathworld.wolfram.com%2FPeanosAxioms.html&usg=AFQjCNHBC8yH1ok7ntNq1TiTKei93yKxdQ)?

Comment: ...or, is $-0$ even a number?

Comment: @user170039 Please don't start the discussion of my mum and me again. :headbang:

Comment: Actually the answer of the question depends on how you define the symbol $-0$. For example, if $-0$ is not a number then you need to **prove** that $0+(-0)=0$ (probably unless you take that as an axiom). When you want to prove that you need to *define* what the summation actually means.

Comment: @user170039 My startoff is from one step further than the set $\omega$ of natural numbers (defined by means of Peano axioms): the set of integers constructed as equivalence classes of $\omega\times\omega$ and defined on them the usual addition.

Comment: @drhab: Actually I wanted to say [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40614/discussion-between-user-170039-and-thomas).

Comment: @user170039 Questions rise like: "What exactly is a number?" "Is $0$ a number, or just a symbol/label that is used in order to communicate about that number?" "If so then can we use $-0$ as another label of the same number?" Palsch his mum might have a very filosophical mind.

Comment: @drhab +1 from my mum :)

Comment: @drhab: Yes. All the questions are important philosophically. But all these questions can be avoided at once (at least it seems to me) if we define $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows, $$|x|=\begin{cases}x& \text{if}\ x>0\\0& \text{if}\ x=0\\-x& \text{if}\ x<0\end{cases}$$then the question simply doesn't make sense because $|x|=-x$ is true only when $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of view points.

### The definition.

[The definition of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers) $\lvert x \rvert$ is

$$
\lvert x \rvert = 
\begin{cases} x & \text{ for } x\geq 0 \\
-x & \text{ for } x< 0
\end{cases}
$$
So according to the definition, $\lvert 0 \lvert = 0$ and $-0 = 0$. and so indeed $\lvert 0 \rvert = - 0$ (they are equal to the same number.

You can object to the definition and maybe in another book you have found another definition. The point is that no matter what definition you have, $\lvert 0 \rvert = -0$ will always be true.

### Group theory

I don't know if the second viewpoint is helpful, but I am guessing that the confusion might be that whether indeed $-0 = 0$. To "prove" this we can turn to the definition. $0$ is the (unique) element $e$ such that $e + x = x$ for all real numbers $x$. Given a real number $x$, what is $-x$? $-x$ is the (unique) element that satisfies the equation $x + \color{blue}{(-x)} = 0$.

Now the uniqueness of these elements is a small exercise in what is called [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory). But for now just take this as facts.

So, to see that $-0 = 0$ you have to "show" that $0 + \color{blue}{0} = 0$. But this is true.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $-0$?

Comment: @user170039: The definition of $-x$ is an element $y$ such that $x + y = 0$. This is exactly satisfied by what we usually denote by $-x$.

Comment: How do you construct $\mathbb{N}$? From $\mathbb{R}$ or using Peano Axioms?

Comment: @user170039: The second viewpoint is just from group theory where we consider the group of real numbers.

Comment: Which "second viewpoint" are you referring to?

Comment: I present two "view points" in my answer. The first is the "definition". One can simply answer the question by saying that by *definition* $0$ is a solution to the equation. The second view point is the one from group theory where we have a precise definition of what $-x$ means in an additive group. There are probably other ways to think about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40614/discussion-between-user-170039-and-thomas).

Answer (score 5):

The set of solutions to $|x| = -x$ is $x \leq 0$. Note that $-0 = (-1) * 0 = 0$.